# Can Self Invoking Async function returns public functions

Tags: javascript, async-await, self-invoking-function

I'm actually new to JavaScript. So here's my question.

From what I learned. I can create a public function (**getHello**) inside a self invoke function (**Example1**) & call the created public function from another self invoke function (**Example2**) like shown below:-

```
// first self-invoke function
const Example1 = (() => {
    // daclare var to hold Hello World
    let hello = 'Hello World'

    return {
        // create public function to passed 'Hello World'
        getHello: () => {    
            return hello
        }
    }
})();

// second self-invoke function - receive 1 argument (Example1 function)
const Example2 = ((e1) => {
    // declare new var
    let newHello = e1.getHello()
    console.log(newHello) // will Output: Hello World

})(Example1);
```

I have tried the above code and it works wonder. Never knew that JavaScript could be so much fun! This means that I can basically share **any private 'data'** inside **Example1** to any other self-invoke functions as long as I create a public function to enable the data sharing.

Anyway, with that in mind. I thought why not I create a **dedicated self-invoking function** to handle any **data fetch from an API**. So to do that I need to put **async** at the self invoke function in order to use await for fetching json data *(as shown below)*

```
// first async self-invoke function
const Example1 = (async() => {
    // get data from API fetch
    let res = await fetch(API_URL)
    let json = await res.json()
    let hello = json

    return {
        // create public function to passed 'Hello World'
        getHello: () => {    
            return hello
        }
    }
})();

// second self-invoke function - receive 1 argument (Example1 function)
const Example2 = ((e1) => {
    // declare new var
    let newHello = e1.getHello() // error occurs here
    console.log(newHello)

})(Example1);
```

But unfortunately, by doing so. It gave me this error saying **"e1.getHello is not a function"**.

I have tried searching the answer or any explanation on google. But I can't seem to find any relevant topic discussing regarding what i just illustrate here.

So the questions would be;-

1) Can an async self-invoke function returns a public function at all? or I shouldn't or not recommended to do this at all?

2) If can/cannot, then why?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`async` function returns `Promise` object. In the given example, `Example1` will be a `Promise` object, not pure object.

So if you want to use it, you have to use `then` or `await` to get the value in the promise.

This will work as expected:

```js
const Example1 = (async() => {
    let res = await fetch(API_URL)
    let json = await res.json()
    let hello = json

    return {
        getHello: () => {    
            return hello
        }
    }
})();

const Example2 = (async (e1) => {
    el = await e1; // **** THIS IS KEY POINT ****
    let newHello = e1.getHello()
    console.log(newHello)
})(Example1);
```

Comment: so since `async` function returns `Promise` as you've mentioned above. That means if `Example2` wants to returns a public function, then any self-invoke function that going to use the public function must use `then` or `await` in order to make use of the value right? And that also means the invoke function will have to use `async` also. Am I right ?

Comment: To be clear, what do you mean by "public function"? it just means not private function?

Comment: The one declared in `return` object in `Example1` function, `getHello` function is a public function right? Since other function can access them.

Comment: Hmm. AFAIK, JS developers don't call it "public function". `Example1` is just assigned an object `{getHello: ... }` by invoking the first async function and that object has a function `getHello`.
Anyway, back to your question. If `Example2` also wants to return an object from the `Example1` information, yes, you have to use `then` or `await` **because `Example1` is a Promise object**. You have to use `then` or `await` to get an information from resolved Promise. Try it in console!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Especially your explanation on Promises and stuff. Easy to understand. Really appreciated it!